# How to get block info by txid in hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

In hyperledger composer, I can get transactionId, but I also need block info.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to get that information from Composer, but there is an [Improvement Proposal issue](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3838) active in GitHub to provide this functionality in the future.

If you need to provide this information visually there is the [Blockchain Explorer](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer) I think this has a REST API so you could make calls to it for block information.